# Python sorted list insertion

Tags: python, list, sorting, insertion

I need help for an exercise in python where I have to fill a preexistent code.

The function take an integer and a sorted list, it inserts the value `a` and then returns the new list, I have to replace the dots by the correct answer

It looks like this :

```py
def insert(a, tab):
    l = list(tab)
    l.append(a)
    i = ...
    while a < ... :
        l[i+1] = ...
        l[i] = a
        i = ...
    return l

>>> insert(3,[1,2,4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It seems like you are supposed to do something similar to bubble sort - swap positions of elements at indices `i` and `i+1`, and keep doing that from right to left until the inserted element is in the correct position. Try solving it yourself with this idea in mind.

Comment: Feel the code structure and variable name is try to confuse people...(or written poorly!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def insert(a, tab):
    l = list(tab)
    l.append(a)
    i = len(l) - 2
    while a < l[i] and i >= 0:
        l[i+1] = l[i]
        l[i] = a
        i -= 1
    return l
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this will crash if the element has to be inserted at the beginning of the list. However, checking `i` in the loop condition to avoid that problem does not seem possible with the original code.

Comment: Good catch. Updated to fix

Comment: Nice fix. For anyone wondering, by having `i>=0` after `a < l[i]`, `l[-1]` will be accessed in the last iteration. In Python that is not a problem, but in other languages it might cause an error. `i>=0` should be checked first, but the provided code template does not allow doing that. That is probably an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** - Nothing new here. Just for a reference, make the variable more descriptive and simplify the code. (for future reading, or *myself*)

```
def insert(x, lst):
    ''' lst is a sorted list'''
    ''' bubble sort - '''
    
    lst.append(x)   # to the end
    
    i = len(lst) - 2
    
    while i >=0 and lst[i] > x:
        lst[i+1], lst[i] = lst[i], x
        i -= 1
    return lst
  

insert(3,[1,2,4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Much better and clean!

Answer (score 0):

Easy, we can even do it by replacing only one of the `...`:

```
def insert(a, tab):
    l = list(tab)
    l.append(a)
    i = ...
    while a < (l.sort() or a) :
        l[i+1] = ...
        l[i] = a
        i = ...
    return l
```

Testing it:

```
>>> insert(3,[1,2,4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -2):

Taking inspiration from the answer above, I would say something that also duplicates the list instead of overwriting on it, like the following

```py
def insert_and_sort(a, tab):
    newtab = list(tab)
    newtab.append(a)
    sort(newtab)
    return newtab
```